# Theoremstyle with line break but non italic text

Tags: theorems, italic, amsthm

I use the theorems (from the amsthm-package) to specify definitions, examples and so on..

I want them to do two things:

1) line break after the label
2) non italic text within the theorem!

I googled a bit and found a solution for the first thing.

I have a MWE for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{defi}[Test]
Foo
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

Can you help me solving the second one??That would be very nice!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply delete `\itshape`...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{defi}[Test]
Foo
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: That was easy! :) Thx!