# Line break after definition

Tags: theorems, mdframed, amsthm

I use the following to have shaded definitions:

```
\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!15}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.5em,
spaceabove=4pt,
mdframed={
  skipabove=8pt,
  skipbelow=6pt,
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor={shadecolor},
  innerleftmargin=2pt,
  innerrightmargin=2pt}
]{shaded}

\declaretheorem[style=shaded,numberlike=theorem]{definition}
```

What do I have to change in order to start every definition with a line break, i.e. so it looks something like this:

> **Defintion 2.15.** 
> Some definition...

I know that you can do this with

```
\theoremstyle{break}
```

for usual theorems. But I haven't figured out how to do it in this case.

Comment: This should help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147397  Instead of `break`, give it another name, maybe `defnbreak`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the theorem style, you can add a `\newline` after the title using the `postheadhook` key.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!15}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadhook=\leavevmode\newline,
spaceabove=4pt,
mdframed={
  skipabove=8pt,
  skipbelow=6pt,
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor={shadecolor},
  innerleftmargin=2pt,
  innerrightmargin=2pt}
]{shaded}

\declaretheorem[style=shaded]{definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Some definition...
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Didn't know this and was looking for exactly something like this.